# React Redux store empty on first load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a login page, that when submitting the form gets a token back from the server.
If the token exists, then the login form should not show.

What is happening though is that when the login page is loaded, the Store is always empty, the page shows the Login Form, the props are then populated and the component updates

**LoginForm.js**

As you can see, when one of the form inputs is updated, it updates the state, hence causing the component to reload - fine.

1. Load LoginForm. Enter details and submit - Works fine
2. Calls API, gets token and saves it in the Store - Works fine
3. Hit F5 and I expect to see "You are already logged in" - Sort of works. The page briefly shows the login form before showing the text

> ```
> import React, { Component } from 'react';
> import { connect } from 'react-redux';
>
> import axios from 'axios';
>
> import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
> import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
> import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
>
> import { addToken } from '../actions'
>
> class LoginForm extends Component {
>
>   constructor(props){
>     super();
>     this.state = {
>       username: null,
>       password: null,
>     }
>   }
>
>   componentDidMount() {
>     console.log('Rendering LoginForm.js');
>   }
>
>   handleSubmit =(e)=>{
>     console.log('sub');
>     axios.post('http://localhost:1337/login', this.state)
>     .then((document) => {
>       if(document.data.message === 'Login Succesful') {
>         this.props.dispatch(addToken(document.data.user));
>       }
>     })
>     .catch((err) => {
>       console.log(err);
>     })
>   }
>
>   handleChange =(e)=> {
>     this.setState({
>       [e.target.id]: e.target.value
>     })
>   }
>
>   render() {
>     if(this.props.token) {
>       console.log(this.props.token);
>       return(
>         <Paper className='loginPaper' zDepth={2}>
>           <p>You are already logged in</p>
>         </Paper>
>       )
>     } else {
>       return(
>         <Paper className='loginPaper' zDepth={2}>
>           <TextField hintText="Username" id='username' floatingLabelText="Username" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
>           <TextField hintText="Password" id='password' floatingLabelText="Password" type="password" onChange={this.handleChange} />
>           <br/><br/>
>           <RaisedButton label="Login" fullWidth={true} onClick {this.handleSubmit}/>
>         </Paper>
>       )
>     }
>   }
> }
>
> //Get updated State
> const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
>   return {
>     token: state.token
>   }
> }
>
> export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginForm)
> ```

**Actions**

```
export const ADD_TOKEN = 'ADD_TOKEN';

export function addToken(token) {
    return {
        type: ADD_TOKEN,
        token,
    }
}

export default {}
```

**reducer**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { ADD_TOKEN } from '../actions';


function token(state = null, action){
  if(action.type === ADD_TOKEN){
    return action.token;
  }

  return state;
}

const merchHunter = combineReducers({
  token
})

export default merchHunter;
```

**App Loader**

```
let store = createStore(
  merchHunter,
  undefined,
  compose(autoRehydrate()
  )
);

persistStore(store);


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
  <MuiThemeProvider>
  <App  />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: So you want the redux store to persist the state after page reload?

Comment: I've just updated my question. Basically it seems that the props are null when the component loads, but then get populated causing the component to re-render

Comment: Do you mean that props are populated only after submitting the form?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't use `redux-persist` library, but it seams that store doesn't rehydrate synchronously. And you have that flash of non-updated `redux` state. I found [this solution](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/126#issuecomment-270120325) in one of discussions for this library.

Simply you can use `Promise` to wait for `redux` state to rehydrate and only then render your app.

Comment: I should have probably added that I'm already using persistStore on my top level component. I am retrieving the token, but when logging out the token as the component renders I get 1) token:null, 2) token: '12345' like the component renders twice

Comment: Please show how you retrieve and pass `token` to `redux` store

Comment: Ok, next time don't forget to mention which libraries you also uses. `redux-persist` is important note to your question :D

Comment: Updated my answer